# How to display part of the array from a Session?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to figure out how to display a certain part from an array. I need to show the user that. So for example:

```
Array ( [id] => 11 [login] => 1 [myusername] => lepel100)
```

Is what `print_r` displays. I want to display Login only.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply using:

```
echo $arrayName['login']
```

Or if it's a `$_SESSION` variable:

```
echo $_SESSION['login']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you have it in your session you can access this by $_SESSION["id"] (if that is your key), or $_SESSION["myusername"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

```
extract($_SESSION);
echo $login;
```